# Node.js Express compact script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently using app.get to resolve URL requests for a website I work on. I'm using app.get to accomplish the following:

> www.site.com/html/contact.html

Is instead translated into

> www.site.com/contact

I am using app.get in the following way:

```
app.get('/team',function(req,res){res.sendfile('team.html',{'root':'./html'});});
app.get('/yada',function(req,res){res.sendfile('yada.html',{'root':'./html'});});
app.get('/home',function(req,res){res.redirect('/');});
app.get('*',function(req, res){res.redirect('/');});
```

This all works splendidly, my question is something rather specific to perhaps JavaScript. What I want to have is something like this:

```
app.get({
   '/team',function() ...,
   '/home',function() ...,
   '/yada',function()...
});
```

Similar to how I can do:

```
var express = requires('express'),
    app = express();
```

Is this possible?

***UPDATE***

I have incorporated an errorHandler with CuriousGuy's solution which works really well:

```
errorHandler = function(err,req,res,next){res.redirect('/');};
app.get('/:page',function(req,res){res.sendFile(req.params.page + '.html',{'root':'./html'});}).use(errorHandler);
```

Albeit I did have to change my filenames to appropriately fit this method of routing, but this works beautifully so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var routes = {
  '/team': function() {},
  '/home', function() {}
};
for (path in routes) {
  app.get(path, routes[path]);
}
```

Though you should be careful with micro-optimizations like this. Using the standard syntax keeps your code clean and readable. Going out of your way to make code "smaller" while sacrificing legibility is not always a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't consider that micro-optimizations (exactly what I was going for) could hinder legibility.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is writing less code to make "non-dot-html" URLs you may use a regular expression:

```
app.get(/^\/(team|yada|contact)\/?$/, function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./html/' + req.params[0] + '.html');
});
app.get('*',function(req, res){res.redirect('/');});
```

Above the `team|yada|contact` part is a list of pages separated by `|`. You can have as many pages in this list as you want, but keep in mind that regular expression may cost a performance of your app.

***Update:***

After a coding awhile I found a solution without a regular expression:

```
app.get('/:page', function(req, res, next) {
    if (['team', 'yada', 'contact'].indexOf(req.params.page) === -1) {
        return next();
    }
    res.sendfile('./html/' + req.params.page + '.html');
});
```

Just add pages you need to `['team', 'yada', 'contact']` array.

***Update 2:***

To demonstrate regular expressions performance I wrote a small script which make the same thing in two different ways -- in first case it replaces a string with regex, and in another case - without regex:

```
var sentence = 'In order to consolidate your success we advise you to continue your work';

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    //case 1: regular expressions replacement
    var word = sentence.replace(/success/, 'SUCCESS');

    //case 2: simple string replacement
    //var word = sentence.replace('success', 'SUCCESS');
}
```

and run it two times with following command (on Linux machine):

```
time node test.js
```

When case 1 is uncommented and case 2 commented I get about `0m1.106s`, otherwise -- `0m0.585s`. So we have regex running two times slower than non-regex equivalent. That's why it is recommended to avoid regular expressions in performance-sensitive apps if possible.

I hope I answered your question, and sorry for my English :)

Comment: CuriousGuy, I've been able to successfully implement both ways you mentioned, I am curious though as to why using regular expressions would hinder performance.

Comment: I truly appreciate that last example of time efficiency using RegEx, I never thought to test things out that way and now I know two new things. You did answer my question, thank you! :)